# Writing to SQLite database. Something strange

Tags: objective-c, sdk, sqlite

I'm using SQLite database. The problem is that data isn't written to base. NSLog shows me "All ok" and `insertSQL` also is correct but still a record in the database does not happened. My code:

```
-(void)saveMessage:(id)sender 
{
    sqlite3 *database;

    databaseName = @"BlogDatabase.sqlite";
    NSArray *documentPaths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
    NSString *documentsDir = [documentPaths objectAtIndex:0];
    databasePath = [documentsDir stringByAppendingPathComponent:databaseName];

    if (sqlite3_open([databasePath UTF8String], &database) == SQLITE_OK)
        {

            NSString *insertSQL = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"insert into \"main\".\"MessagesData\" ( \"MessageText\", \"MessageDate\") values ( '%@', '%@');", _textField.text, [[NSDate alloc] init]];
            NSLog(@"%@", insertSQL);
            const char *insert_stmt = [insertSQL UTF8String];
            sqlite3_stmt *compiledStatement;


            if(sqlite3_prepare_v2(database, insert_stmt, -1, &compiledStatement, NULL) != SQLITE_OK)
                {
                    NSAssert1(0, @"Error while creating add statement. '%s'", sqlite3_errmsg(database)); 
                    }else{
                    if (sqlite3_step(compiledStatement) == SQLITE_DONE)
                        {
                            NSLog(@"All ok");
                            } else {
                            NSLog(@"FAIL");
                            }
                        }
            sqlite3_finalize(compiledStatement);
            }
    sqlite3_close(database);
    }
```

Comment: In which database you are looking for. app db ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**In which database you are looking for? app db ?**

Can you check out the number of record, just count the records.

> SELECT count(*) FROM **your_table_name**

I doubt it whether you have any value in your _textField.text and date you are just initializing no setting it. and lets assume everything is fine, then

you should use **BlogDatabase.MessagesData** not main.MessagesData.

first try to run that insertQuery which you NSLog in your plain terminal. 
    **sqlite3 [app_db_path]/BlogDatabase.sqlite**

Comment: Database name is BlogDatabase.sql. Has table named MessagesData. There I have already 2 records and `SELECT count(*) FROM your_table_name` shows me this count. The text of `_text.Field.text`have from iphone keyboard (100% value exists). From NSLog I have `insert into "main"."MessagesData" ( "MessageText", "MessageDate") values ( 'Some new message', '2012-04-01 17:11:13 +0000');` and `All ok`.

Comment: Then you should use **BlogDatabase.MessagesData** not main.MessagesData. And first try to run that insertQuery which you NSLog in your plain terminal. sqlite3 BlogDatabase.sqlite

Comment: Changed to `BlogDatabase.MessagesData`. In this case I received an error `'Error while creating add statement. 'no such table: BlogDatabase.MessagesData''`. Older version works fine from Terminal.

Comment: Ok can you read for me the NSLog(@"%@", insertSQL); and databasePath. and check your databasePath does exist or not ?

Comment: NSLog(@"%@", insertSQL); - `insert into "main"."MessagesData" ( "MessageText", "MessageDate") values ( 'Some new message', '2012-04-01 17:57:03 +0000');`. databasePath - `/Users/romansvarychevskyi/Library/Application Support/iPhone Simulator/5.0/Applications/D69020CC-E7D5-4A57-950E-777E55FF62C4/Documents/BlogDatabase.sqlite`. I check existing of my database in delegate file, also I am reading from this database (my older messages). Reading works fine.

Comment: Ok now open the terminal and type **sqlite3 /Users/romansvarychevskyi/Library/Application Support/iPhone Simulator/5.0/Applications/D69020CC-E7D5-4A57-950E-777E55FF62C4/Documents/BlogDatabase.sqlite** and run the insert into "main"."MessagesData" ( "MessageText") values ( 'Some new message');. i guess it will not run because first of "main" is not the database name in your case and second thing is both should be in double quotes together "<database_name>.<table_name>'

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/9563/discussion-between-romanhouse-and-praveen-k)

Answer (score 1):

You have to modify your code as below.

```
-(void)saveMessage:(id)sender 
{
sqlite3 *database;

databaseName = @"BlogDatabase.sqlite";
NSArray *documentPaths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
NSString *documentsDir = [documentPaths objectAtIndex:0];
databasePath = [documentsDir stringByAppendingPathComponent:databaseName];


  NSFileManager *fileManager = [NSFileManager defaultManager];

  BOOL success = [fileManager fileExistsAtPath:file];

  if(!success) {
      databasePath = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:databaseName ofType:nil];
  }
```

Also put NSLog(@"Error. '%s'", sqlite3_errmsg(database)); after each database operation completed. (ie; after, sqlite3_step, sqlite3_prepare etc). This will print the exact error message while using database.

Comment: Modified my code and put NSLogs. Any changes, all databese operations work fine.